# Where is OS X saving launchctl changes

Tags: macos, launchctl, afp

I'm activating my AFP-Server in OSX with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
```

It is running now, but I'm wondering because the file contains no changes!? Where is the system saving the setting?

Comment: I had thought it was in `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`, but after testing that's apparently not the case. There's an entry in there for com.apple.AppleFileServer, but it has `Disabled` set to `true` whether or not it's loaded. So now I really want to know too...

Comment: You must say which version of MacOS 10.? this is. Since Apple keeps changing system directories, files and permissions in every version or sub-version, without warning.

Answer (score 2):

##### The disabled-launchctl-items file location:

I seem to have found the location: it's in `/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.plist`, as something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>com.apple.AppleFileServer</key>
    <false/>
    ....
</dict>
</plist>
```

Since this file lists *disabled* launch daemons, `<false/>` = *not* disabled = loaded, and `<true/>` = disabled = *not* loaded. There are also files with user IDs in the names, e.g. `disabled.503.plist`, which store similar info for launch agents (which can be loaded/unloaded differently for each user).

#### Related issue

Another complication I found is that if you enable or disable the file server in System Preferences -> Sharing pane -> File Sharing option, the daemon is loaded or unloaded immediately, but the setting doesn't seem to be saved to the file until later (maybe only next restart?). Changes make with `launchctl`, on the other hand, are saved to the file immediately. But this does mean that the file's contents doesn't necessarily represent the true state of affairs.